# UIImage decompression causing scrolling lag

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I have this app with a full screen tableView that displays a bunch of tiny images. Those images are pulled from the web, processed on a background thread, and then saved to disk using something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 0);
    // code that adds some glosses, shadows, etc 
    UIImage *output = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    NSData* cacheData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(output);
    [cacheData writeToFile:thumbPath atomically:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.image = output; // refreshes the cell using KVO
    });
});
```

This code is only executed the first time the cell is displayed (since after that the image is already on disk). In that case, the cell is loaded using:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIImage *savedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:thumbPath];

    if(savedImage) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.image = savedImage; // refreshes the cell using KVO
        });
    }
});
```

My problem is that in the first case, scrolling is butter smooth. But in the 2nd case (where it's reading the image directly from disk), scrolling is super jerky, even once the image is loaded. Drawing is what's causing the lag. Using Instruments, I see `copyImageBlockSetPNG`, `png_read_now` and `inflate` are taking up most of the cpu (they aren't when assigning `self.image` to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`)

I'm assuming this happens because in the first case the UIImage is a raw output of the drawing, whereas in the second case it has to decompress the PNG every time it's drawing it. I tried using JPGs instead of PNGs and I get similar results.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe to have it only decompress the PNG the first time it gets drawn?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is that `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` is cached and lazy loading. If you want to do something like this, instead use this code on your background queue:

```
// Assuming ARC
NSData* imageFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thumbPath];
UIImage* savedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageFileData];

// Dispatch back to main queue and set image...
```

Now, with this code, the actual decompression of the image data will still be lazy and cost a little bit, but not nearly as much as the file access hit you're getting with the lazy loading in your code example.

Since you're still seeing a performance issue, you can also force UIImage to decompress the image on the background thread:

```
// Still on background, before dispatching to main
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(100, 100)); // this isn't that important since you just want UIImage to decompress the image data before switching back to main thread
[savedImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// dispatch back to main thread...
```

Comment: This definitely made scrolling smoother, but not nearly as smooth as in the first case...

Comment: @samvermette Right, see my comment at the end of the code block. In the first instance, you've already got a fully-decompressed image while in the second case, you haven't got a decompressed image yet (UIImage is lazy). If you have lots and lots of these little images, batching them by row and loading them all at once may help.

Comment: @samvermette I edited the answer with some example code that you can put in the background queue...

Comment: YES! I was actually writing this code as I saw your answer. Was wondering whether it might be practice, but this definitely fixes my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Good question, good answer. If you're not already, you could also throw the decompressed image in an `NSCache` to avoid hitting the disk again.

Comment: Whoa, unbelievable the difference it makes to do the second change to force the decompression on the background thread. Butter smooth scrolling here after that change.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the decompression. I found that using imageNamed performed better than initWithData though.

Answer (score 16):

Jason's tip about pre-drawing the image to decompress it is the key, but you'll get even better performance by copying the whole image and discarding the original.

Images created at runtime on iOS seem to be better optimised for drawing than ones that have been loaded from a file, even after you've forced them to decompress. For that reason, you should load like this (it's also a good idea to put the decompressed image into an NSCache so you don't have to keep reloading it):

```
- (void)loadImageWithPath:(NSString *)path block:(void(^)(UIImage *image))block
{
    static NSCache *cache = nil;
    if (!cache)
    {
        cache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
    }

    //check cache first
    UIImage *image = [cache objectForKey:path];
    if (image)
    {
        block(image);
        return;
    }

    //switch to background thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

        //load image
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

        //redraw image using device context
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, YES, 0);
        [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        //back to main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            //cache the image
            [cache setObject:image forKey:path];

            //return the image
            block(image);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this with JPEG images and 1) it's slow and 2) it still lags when the image view is going to enter the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Still lags? That's curious since the code above doesn't block the main thread at all. How are you setting the images - is there a chance you're still loading something synchronously?

Comment: Also, how big are the images? If they're full screen on a retina iPad then they will always lag however you load them. Trick there is to load low res version first then swap in retina image when the scrolling stops.

Comment: I was using thumbnails and asynchronously loading full size on `NSOperationQueue`. It was async, but still when assigned to the image view (on main queue) it lagged (in case the user was dragging). The problem was, that **the images were very big** (full size of iPhone 5 photo = 30MB decompressed). I ended up not displaying full size photo.

Comment: For images that size you should use a CATiledLayer, or if you don't need the full image, downscale it to something reasonable when you redraw it after loading.

Comment: The reason for the lag in your case is not loading or decompressing the images, it's that the maximum supported OpenGL texture size on iOS is 2048x2048 (or 4096x4096 depending on the device). If you try to display an image larger than that then it has to be down sampled at runtime, or split into multiple textures, or drawn using CPU instead of GPU, or something equally slow and horrible.

Comment: For the above code my experiments have shown that in my case the scale parameter in UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions should be set to 1.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2017?

Comment: @BarrettJ it will still work, but I'd advise using ImageIO now instead.

Answer (score 6):

Another way image decompression:

```
 NS_INLINE void forceImageDecompression(UIImage *image)
 {
  CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef), 8, CGImageGetWidth(imageRef) * 4, colorSpace,kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
  if (!context) { NSLog(@"Could not create context for image decompression"); return; }
  CGContextDrawImage(context, (CGRect){{0.0f, 0.0f}, {CGImageGetWidth(imageRef), CGImageGetHeight(imageRef)}}, imageRef);
  CFRelease(context);
}
```

Using:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u.jpg", pageIndex]];
  forceImageDecompression(image);

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [((UIImageView*)page)setImage:image];
  });
}
```